# Join two strings in Scala with one to one mapping

Tags: scala

I have two strings in Scala

**Input 1** : "a,c,e,g,i,k"

**Input 2** : "b,d,f,h,j,l"

How do I join the two Strings in Scala?

**Required output** = "ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,kl"

I tried something like:

```
var columnNameSetOne:Array[String] = Array();    //v1 = "a,c,e,g,i,k"
var columnNameSetTwo:Array[String] = Array();    //v2 = "b,d,f,h,j,l"
```

After I get the input data as mentioned above

```
columnNameSetOne = v1.split(",")
columnNameSetTwo = v2.split(",");

val newColumnSet = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(columnNameSetOne.length, columnNameSetTwo.length)).mapToObj(j => (columnNameSetOne(j) + columnNameSetTwo(j))).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

println(newColumnSet)
```

But I am getting error on j

Also, I am not sure if this would work!

Comment: whats wrong with zip?

Comment: What error are you getting? That will help the community better address your question.

Comment: @RamanMishra, didn't get you exactly

Comment: @DylanKnowles: it just gives j: <error>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object Solution1 extends App {

  val input1 = "a,c,e,g,i,k"
  val input2 = "b,d,f,h,j,l"

  val i1= input1.split(",")
  val i2 = input2.split(",")

  val x =i1.zipAll(i2, "", "").map{
    case (a,b)=> a + b
  }

  println(x.mkString(","))

}
 //output : ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,kl
```

Comment: I also need to check: 1) If input1 or input2 contain elements with space or hyphen then replace them with $ (dollar) 2) If input1 or input2 start with a number, then append $(dollar) before the number. Can this be done in scala without using for or while loops, I mean using .map and .filter etc.?

Comment: @Nick You are changing your question after others have already answered.  _Don't_ do that.  If you need something else, ask another question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Ok, sorry about that! I'll delete my comment then. Please advise.

Comment: `case c` can never happen. Should use `zipAll()` to cover inputs of different lengths.

Comment: @jwvh yes it can't you are right. i will update it thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do using zip function on list.

```
val v1 = "a,c,e,g,i,k"
val v2 = "b,d,f,h,j,l"

val list1 = v1.split(",").toList
val list2 = v2.split(",").toList

list1.zip(list2).mkString(",") // res0: String = (a,b),( c,d),( e,f),( g,h),( i,j),( k,l)
```

Comment: Not clear if the OP wants a list rather than a string, but +1.

Comment: Need to add mkString to get the string. Updated the answer.